Checking current hostname (just systemd, no avahi)
I have configured systemd-netword to enable mDNS.
My hostname is configured to "myhost".
But in the network there is another host with the same name, so the systemd mDNS system assign to my host a suffix to make it unique "myhost" (and this is good).
But, how can I check wich suffix is currently assigned to my host from linux command line?
Tried hostnamectl but only get the original hostname, not the current one with prefix.
